# Having an issue uploading csv file to my parse app

Tags: ios, csv, parse-platform

I’m having an issue uploading my the attached csv file to my parse app. It says :

line 22515, column 0: wrong number of fields in line

for every upload I do. Including when I upload a slightly smaller csv file (which ironically doesn't have a line 22515 in it).

Any tips/help?

Comment: show the code you have tried for uploading csv file.

Comment: Are you using a `ParseFile` as the column type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 22k is the max excel rows limit in old excel versions I believe till 2010, maybe that has something to do with this...